# How to offload TLS client certificate authentication to a simple proxy

Tags: proxy, ssl, certificates, https, http-proxy

I have a web application that is accessible only through HTTPS with client certificate authentication. I need to run some analysis tools which don't cope well with client certificate authentication. A full blown proxy like ZAP or BurpSuite works but is too heavy-weight. I am seeking for a lean solution that can be launched from the command line without GUI etc.

Specifically, how can I set up a proxy that is locally accessible through HTTP or HTTPS, where the proxy handles all the client certificate business with the actual remote application?